# How to shutdown tasks when MainProcess receives SIGTERM

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm on Heroku and therefore only have 10 seconds to shutdown all tasks when the `SIGTERM` signal is sent. Some of my tasks will create subprocesses that will run for minutes at a time. It is OK for these tasks to be shutdown halfway through. What is the best way to terminate the tasks and their child processes?

My first approach, below, is to register a listener on the `SIGTERM` signal of the worker (MainProcess). From there, it'll revoke all running tasks of type `my_long_running_task_that_i_can_safely_end`. I've also considered just sending `app.control.broadcast('shutdown')` to shut down all worker processes.

From within my tasks, I'll register a listener for the `SIGTERM` signal and gracefully shut itself down.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
from celery.signals import worker_ready
from celery import platforms

worker_ready.connect(endit)

old_term = None
old_int = None

def endit(**kwargs):
  global old_term
  global old_int

  old_term = platforms.signals[signal.SIGTERM]
  old_int = platforms.signals[signal.SIGINT]

  platforms.signals[signal.SIGTERM] = signal_term_handler
  platforms.signals[signal.SIGINT] = signal_term_handler

def signal_term_handler(signal, frame):
  active = app.control.inspect().active()
  # ****** active == None here ---- This is not what I expect ******

  app.control.broadcast('shutdown')
  # ****** This did not appear to shutdown my worker processes either ******

  if signal == 2:
    old_int(signal, frame)
  elif signal == 15:
    old_term(signal, frame)
```

The problems I've run into is that `app.control.inspect().active()` returns `None`. `app.control.broadcast('shutdown')` does not appear to shut down the worker processes.

Is this the best appraoch? I feel as if there are so many ways to do this and I don't want to go down the wrong path.

Thanks

Comment: Correlating question on google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/8zpMOddaISo

Comment: I'm having a similar situation. I'm able to listen to sigterm within the task and in the handler I'm able to pass on the sigterm to the subprocess which in turn is also listening to sigterm and so the subprocess exits. But the problem is that the worker that was executing the task continues to live on. In my case the task that launches the subprocess waits for the subprocess to finish.